# Git-TF pushes changes to a wrong server

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, tfs-migration, git-tf

I tried to migrate Git repository to TFS with all history using git-tf. I used the following command lines:

```
git tf --force configure http://tfs.YYYY.net/tfs/Collection '$\RepositoryName'
git tf checkin --deep --autosquash --preview
```

The problem is that in the end the git-tfs-id is

git-tfs-id: [http://**tfs-server**.YYYY.net:8080]$/RepositoryName;C32524

and the changesets are not on TFS.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi AlinM, any update on this? Have you figured out it?

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT, unfortunately i haven't figured it out. In the end I migrate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the server is not configured correctly. It has a internal url and a public one, it looks like the server is configured to broadcast its internal name.

The public URL is what's sent back to the client, the internal name is what's used internally on the server and by an optional load balancer.

During setup:

[image]

After setup:

[image]

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/open-admin-console?view=azure-devops#view-or-change-the-public-url

In case of a migrated server, it could also be an issue with your local workspace cache. Try refreshing the cache explicitly against the new server:

That could also be your local workspace cache is dirty. Try explicitly refreshing the cache and optionally deleting the old workspaces from your computer: `
Try running below command to refresh the cache:

```
tf workspaces /s:http://tfs-server:8080
```

Or removing them from your local workspace cache explicitly before adding them again:

```
tf vc workspaces /remove:* /collection:https://old-server-collection-url
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights and also I don't know who's the admin. The wrong server is an old one we used but now it's offline. May you are right and some settings were left with the old server.

Comment: I found out who the admin was and he said that the public URL is ok and in any other place the tfs server name was ok. Also in the local workspace cache the old tfs server wasn't there. In the end I did the migration manually. So thank  you for your effort!